# netmask: command not found

Tags: linux, linux-networking

I purchased a new server with a few ip's so I modified the /etc/network/interfaces file recently so that my ip's can go live. While editing that file I created a backup and deleted the original file. I recreated the interfaces file using the touch command and gave +x permissions but now, when trying to restart the interface (/etc/network/interfaces restart) I get all sorts of errors:

```
/etc/network/interfaces: line 10: iface: command not found
/etc/network/interfaces: line 11: address: command not found
/etc/network/interfaces: line 12: netmask: command not found
/etc/network/interfaces: line 13: auto: command not found
```

Can any1 point what I forgot to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The command is `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. The `interfaces` file is a configuration file (and doesn’t need to be executable).